# Single input instead of multiple input in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(SELECT a FROM Table 1 WHERE a=10 AND B=2 LIMIT 1000) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM Table 2 WHERE a=10 AND B=2 LIMIT 1000) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM Table 3 WHERE a=10 AND B=2 LIMIT 1000)
```

---

Expecting:- instead of entering 3 times values in t1, t2, t3 tables

I want to fetch the data from 3 tables, where a=10 and b=2. But instead of entering data 3 Times separately in each table, I want it to enter only once. So can we do that

Thank you in advance

Comment: What 3 values? What are you trying to accomplish? One select statement for 3 tables?

Comment: *I need to put it only 1 time it has **to change** in 3 tables with same data* ?? Your query changes nothing.

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch the data from 3 tables, where a=10 and b=2. But instead of entering data 3 Times separately in each table, I want it to enter only once. So can we do that

Comment: What do you mean by "Entering data". Do you mean you don't want to have to write such verbose SQL to get what you want? If that's the case, then to your question "So can we do that?", "no" is the answer.

Comment: Entering data:- the value what we are trying to fetch from a particular table eg:- 10 value from table 1, 2, 3

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirement. Please [edit] your question to show some sample data and your desired result set. Or ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, but something like an inner join might be what you need:

SELECT t1.a, t2.a, t3.a
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.b = t2.b
INNER JOIN t3
ON t2.b = t3.b;

I'm assuming that a and b are referring to the same things in all 3 tables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).